# Date in Makefile recipes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to create log files with time stamps. In my Makefile, I get the date as following:

```
DATE                = $(shell date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
```

In my recipe I do a couple of grep on the log file:

```
my_long_run: 
cd $(MYDIR); Running a tool for a long time | tee -i ./Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE)
@sleep 2
@grep -iq "Status of the Job:0" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE)
@if [ ! -z "$(SOME_ENV_VAR)" ]; then ln -fs $(ANOTHER_ENV_VAR)/my_generate_file; fi; \
echo "$$dependencyTree" > $@; \
echo -e "\nWarning Summary:" >> $@; \
if grep -iq "warn.*total" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE)  ; then grep -i "warn.*total" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) >> $@;  fi; \
if grep -iq "warn.*check" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) ; then grep -i "warn.*check" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) >> $@; fi; \
echo -e "\nError Summary:" >> $@; \
if grep -iq "error.*total" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) ; then grep -i "error.*total" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) >> $@; fi; \
if grep -iq "error.*check" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) ; then grep -i "error.*check" Log/my_long_run_log.$(DATE) >> $@; fi;
```

The problem is:
At the first line, the Date is expanded as: 2020-02-26-09:14:**09**.
But the grep command looks for a file with time stamp: 2020-02-26-09:14:**10**
grep: Log/my_long_run_log.2020-02-26-09:14:10: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [my_long_run] Error 2.
And then of course I need repeat this run with a runtime of 6-7 hours just because of this grep failure.

```
sleep 2
```

is intentional. As I have some lags in my server and the files take a while to appear. But nevertheless, to my knowledge, Makefile expands all the recipes before executing the commands. Why would $(DATE) have two values for one single recipe?
sorry, for not providing an actual MWE, rather an abstracted one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:=` to define your variable, instead of `=`. When using `=`, it is evaluated every time it is referenced, while when using `:=` it is only evaluated when you define it, and its value is then used later on.

This is explained in [GNU make's manual: The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), where variables defined with `:=` are called `simply expanded variables` and variables defined with `=` are called `recursively expanded variables`.

> The value of a simply expanded variable is scanned once and for all, expanding any references to other variables and functions, when the variable is defined.

Your Makefile would then just be like this:

```
DATE := $(shell date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
```